# $x^4-6x^3-73x^2+kx+m=0$, $\alpha\beta=\gamma\delta=4$, $\alpha^2-3(1+\sqrt{10})\alpha+4=0$, equations satisfied by $\beta$, $\gamma$ and $\delta$

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, roots

> The equation $x^4-6x^3-73x^2+kx+m=0$ has two positive roots, $\alpha$,
> $\beta$ and two negative roots $\gamma$, $\delta$. It is given that
> $\alpha\beta=\gamma\delta=4$. Show that
> $\alpha^2-3(1+\sqrt{10})\alpha+4=0$, and find similar quadratic
> equations satisfied by $\beta$, $\gamma$ and $\delta$.

Unsure how to approach this question. So far I have:

- Found $k=-24$ and $m=16$
- Shown $(\alpha+\beta)(\gamma+\delta)=-81$
- Found quadratic equation with roots $\alpha+\beta$ and $\gamma+\delta$ to be $x^2-6x-81=0$
- Found $\alpha+\beta=3+3\sqrt{10}$ and $\gamma+\delta=3-3\sqrt{10}$

Thanks for any help!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3885036/question-about-the-roots-of-polynomials-and-algebraic-manipulation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost there. You showed that $$\alpha+\beta=3+3\sqrt{10}$$ and you are given $$\alpha\beta=4$$
So a quadratic equation with roots $\alpha$ and $\beta$ is $$x^2-(\alpha+\beta)x+\alpha\beta=0$$
or $$x^2-3(1+\sqrt{10})x+4=0$$
Since you know $\alpha$ is root:
$$\alpha^2-3(1+\sqrt{10})\alpha+4=0$$
You have the same equation for $\beta$. Apply similar reasoning for the other parameters.

**Note** you can multiply the above equation by $\beta$ and you have a linear equation for $\alpha$, in case you want to solve for $\alpha$ and you find quadratics difficult :)